# How to change the information in the Week column based on the weekday name given by the system

Tags: r

I'm having trouble changing the information in the `Week` column based on the weekday name given by the system. I do it like this: `df1$Week <- weekdays(df1$Week)`, but it gives an error, how to adjust?

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(date = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-02","2021-07-04","2021-07-04","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

> df1
        date      Week
1 2021-06-30 Wednesday
2 2021-06-30 Wednesday
3 2021-07-02    Friday
4 2021-07-04 Wednesday
5 2021-07-04 Wednesday
6 2021-07-09    Friday
7 2021-07-09    Friday
8 2021-07-09    Friday


df1$Week <- weekdays(df1$Week)

Error in UseMethod("weekdays") : 
  no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Like, whats your desired output

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `weekdays()` converts something from a `Date` or `POSIXt` type (e.g. `2022-04-07`) to a weekday (e.g. `Wednesday`). Your column `Week` already contains a weekday - and because it's in `character` format, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are needing to correct the day of the week due to inaccuracies, then you can convert the `date` to a date format, then use `weekdays` to get the correct day of the week. But unsure of your desired output.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         Week = weekdays(date))
```

**Output**

```
        date      Week
1 2021-06-30 Wednesday
2 2021-06-30 Wednesday
3 2021-07-02    Friday
4 2021-07-04    Sunday
5 2021-07-04    Sunday
6 2021-07-09    Friday
7 2021-07-09    Friday
8 2021-07-09    Friday
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the character format of `date` column also your assignment is `df1$Week <- weekdays(df1$Week)` wrong:

```
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df1$Week <- weekdays(df1$date)
df1
```

```
        date     Week
1 2021-06-30 Mittwoch
2 2021-06-30 Mittwoch
3 2021-07-02  Freitag
4 2021-07-04  Sonntag
5 2021-07-04  Sonntag
6 2021-07-09  Freitag
7 2021-07-09  Freitag
8 2021-07-09  Freitag
```